# How to get share count from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to get the shares count of a post(not a url) using the Facebook Graph API. I was able to do it using FQL but seeing that it will be dropped by August I'm looking for a non-depricated way to do it.

I'm new to this and would really appreciate any help. I'm using the graph API on python.

I saw the following pages:

1. [How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)
2. [Can i get lots of share counts using facebook graph API? And how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652491/can-i-get-lots-of-share-counts-using-facebook-graph-api-and-how-to-do-it)
3. [Using Facebook Graph API 2.2 to get like and share count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563193/using-facebook-graph-api-2-2-to-get-like-and-share-count)
4. [How to get facebook share, like, comment count for a url with graph api only (in a non-deprecated way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940403/how-to-get-facebook-share-like-comment-count-for-a-url-with-graph-api-only-in)

However, I couldn't find a way that worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer at

- [Facebook Graph API: engagement count breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855221/facebook-graph-api-engagement-count-breakdown/33866248#33866248)

You should be able to call

```
/?fields=id,share,og_object{engagement{count},likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.limit(0).summary(true)}&id=http://www.google.com
```

which return something like

```
{
  "id": "http://www.google.com",
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 2,
    "share_count": 31135003
  },
  "og_object": {
    "engagement": {
      "count": 31135003
    },
    "likes": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 87935,
        "can_like": true,
        "has_liked": false
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "summary": {
        "order": "chronological",
        "total_count": 1323,
        "can_comment": true
      }
    },
    "id": "381702034999"
  }
}
```